# Dúvida - HashMap & List

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, hashmap

Minha necessidade era a seguinte: Um relatório que traria o Evento e o número de reservas de hotel que estava associada aquele Evento. E assim se seguiu como mostra o código abaixo:

```
    List<IHotelReservation> iHotelReservationList = Lists.newArrayList();

    iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.hotelReservationDao.listByReservationStatus(hotelReservationFilter));
    iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.omnibeesHotelReservationDao.listByReservationStatus(hotelReservationFilter));

    Map<Event, Integer> hotelReservationMap = Maps.newHashMap();

    for (IHotelReservation iHotelReservation : iHotelReservationList) {
        int hotelReservationQtd = 1;
        if (hotelReservationMap.containsKey(iHotelReservation.getEvent())) {
            hotelReservationQtd = hotelReservationMap.get(iHotelReservation.getEvent())+1;
        }
        hotelReservationMap.put(iHotelReservation.getEvent(), hotelReservationQtd);
    }
    this.result.include("hotelReservationMap", hotelReservationMap);
}
```

Ainda preciso que se retorne um Map usando Event como key. Porém agora com o número de Allocations dado aquele Event, não mais de HotelReservations. Vale ressaltar que possuo um List getAllocationList() em IHotelReservation.

Comment: Veja se eu entendi: "1 Event tem 1-N HotelReservetion", e, "1 Event tem 1-N Allocation", é isso? Não seria melhor adicionar a Event uma Lista de HotelReservetion e umaListade Allocation (nota, se não for possível ou indesejável alterar a classe Evento, você pode criar um "EventHolder" que teria 1 Event e as Listas HotelReservetion e Allocation desse Event)?

Comment: Event não tem HotelReservation. 1-N HotelReservation tem 1 Event. 1-N Allocation tem 1 HotelReservation. Há muita resistência em se alterar a classe Event.

Comment: E qual é a relação direta entre Event e Allocation? Você quer simplesmente somar os Allocations de todos os HotelReservation que tem um determinado Event, fazendo isto para cada Event?

Comment: Exatamente. A única relação que Allocation tem com Event é HotelReservation. Imagino que consiga percorrer a lista de HotelReservation e pegando seus Allocations.

Comment: E o que "hotel_reservation_id" tem haver? Não consegui ver ainda porque ele seria necessário para implementar essa funcionalidade.

Comment: Pois é. Agora conversando eu percebi que não preciso dele pois antes eu estava imaginando que teria de percorrer uma lista de Allocations e comparar os hotel_reservation_id com o id do HotelReservation. Entende ? Mas só preciso percorrer a lista de Allocations do HotelReservation.

Comment: Se vc já for capaz de responder sua pergunta, responda ela e aceite a resposta; caso contrário, vc precisará editar sua pergunta: remova o negócio do "hotel_reservation_id", mostre o método de "IHotelReservation" que retorna a lista de Allocations e diga qual é tipo do retorno (é um List<Allocation>?). Eu imagino que vc quer mais um ´Map<Event, Integer> evento_AllocationsAssociadosAoEvento´, se é isso acione-o a pergunta e explique o que conversamos aqui no comentários.

Comment: Não sou capaz ainda de responder minha pergunta e a editei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas pequenas alterações no código são suficientes para alterar o que código faz para que ele passe a dizer quantos Allocations estão associadas a cada Event ao invés de dizer quantos IHotelReservation estão associados a cada Event.

Há comentários nas coisas importantes do código para explicá-las.

```
List<IHotelReservation> iHotelReservationList = Lists.newArrayList();

iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.hotelReservationDao.listByReservationStatus(hotelReservationFilter));
iHotelReservationList.addAll(this.omnibeesHotelReservationDao.listByReservationStatus(hotelReservationFilter));

//A variável segue um padrão meu de nomenclatura para maps, que é "nomeDobjetoDaKey_NomeDoObjetoDoValue", ou seja, na key temos um "evento" e para este evento temos no Value o "TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento"
Map<Event, Integer> evento_TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento = Maps.newHashMap();

for (IHotelReservation iHotelReservation : iHotelReservationList) {
    //Na linha abaixo colocamos em "allocationsQtd" o total de Allocations do iHotelReservation da iteração atual do loop
    int allocationsQtd = iHotelReservation.getAllocationList().size(); //tenha certeza de que "getAllocationList()" não retornará null, caso contrário, vc terá que tratar isso
    if (evento_TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento.containsKey(iHotelReservation.getEvent())) {
        //Entramos no if se já colocamos o Event no map, e nesse caso, vamos incrementar allocationsQtd com a quantidade de Allocations que já estava no map
        allocationsQtd += evento_TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento.get(iHotelReservation.getEvent());
    }
    //Na linha abaixo iserimos o Event pela primeira vez no map, ou, atualizamos o valor dele no map
    evento_TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento.put(iHotelReservation.getEvent(), allocationsQtd);
}
this.result.include("evento_TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento", evento_TotalDeAllocationsAssociadosAoEvento);
```